# how can image be downloaded to storage from server?

Tags: image, storage, codenameone

how can image can be downloaded from server to mobile's storage in code name one?

`ImageDownloadService.createImageToStorage(imageUrl, null, "image.png")` creates an image on storage but it is blank and it is not opening.

Comment: You do not give enough data - what server, what storage, how do you access the server, what programming language...? Is this a web application or utility script...?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to download use `Util.downloadToStorage()` otherwise I would recommend `URLImage` rather than `ImageDownloadService`.

Comment: What's an appropriate value for the Storage file parameter?  Is it just any name I give it, or do I have to create the file before the call to createToStorage().  And should it really be Storage object, rather than Storage file, in the method signature?

Comment: Any name but it needs to be unique. ImageDownloadService saves an object which means you can't have code that just reads it to an image. The other two save a file to storage.

Comment: Thanks, Shai! Boy, it seems you sure work hard answering all the questions here and on the forum.